# CMake ignores imported shared object

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a CMake project which builds a shared object, let's call it `libfoo.so` which has to be dynamically linked to another shared object `libbar.so`. This later one is not built from files contained in the project itself but rather just copied into the build directory from an external source during the invocation of `cmake`. To make CMake aware of this file I've tried doing the following:

```
add_library(bar SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set_target_properties(bar PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION some/path/to/libbar.so
)
```

And then to build `libfoo.so` I do (in another CMakeLists.txt in an unrelated directory):

```
add_library(foo SHARED ...)
target_link_libraries(foo bar)
```

However, this does not work as desired, when running `make VERBOSE=1` after `cmake` the output shows that `libfoo.so` is linked with `-lbar` instead of `libbar.so`.

If necessary I can try creating a minimal working example but maybe someone has encountered the same problem and can tell me what's going wrong.

Comment: Seems to me that everything is working fine. If the full name is `libbar.so` and you see that `libfoo.so` links to `bar`, then it is correct. Try `readelf -d libfoo.so` to see if `libbar.so` is in the `DT_NEEDED` section.

Comment: I don't think it's working as intended, I have already inspected `libfoo.so` with `objdump -p` and `libbar.so` is not listed as adynamic depedency. Also if I instead call `target_link_libraries(foo some_non_existent_target)` CMake will still try to link with `-lsome_non_existent_target`.

Comment: Any error messages we should be aware of then? Are you actually getting link errors or runtime errors?

Comment: Ah yes, linking fails because `-lbar` can't be found, I should probably add that. I think the problem is that `bar` is not a recognized target  at the point where I call `target_link_libraries`. But I don't understand why this is the case, I assumed that the `GLOBAL` flag would make the target `bar` available throughout the whole project.

Comment: `set_target_properties` seems to be wrong.  You are supposed to set a full path to target but your example shows a relative path.  Can you post the actual command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmake doesn't support imported libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813746/cmake-doesnt-support-imported-libraries)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmake:missing and no known rule to make it when I import a prebuilt library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478323/cmakemissing-and-no-known-rule-to-make-it-when-i-import-a-prebuilt-library) This duplicate question may address the issue more directly.